# Python: Datetime, Error with strftime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I try to convert a time string to a date time object, but it alway throws the following error:

```
ValueError: time data '2016-04-07 06:34:39' does not match format '%Y-%m-%w %H:%M:%S'
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think error is in your datetime format where you have %w what means "     Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday." and fail when you have your day greather than 6 :)

```
'2016-04-07 06:34:39' format '%Y-%m-%w %H:%M:%S'
```

**Change %w to %d:**

```
'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Let me know if that help you.

[Python datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)